# Months between dates in Flow

Tags: formula, formula-field, visual-workflow

I am new to Salesforce and need to know how to implement a months between dates fromula. The formula needs to be created in Flow Builder as a formula resource. Most of the examples I looked at refers to Apex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula can be utilized to get month difference in Flow.

```
MONTH( {!EndDate}) + 12 - MONTH( {!StartDate}) + 12 * (YEAR(EndDate) - YEAR(StartDate) -1)
```

StartDate - A variable of Date Type

EndDate - A variable of Date Type

DateDiff - A Variable of Number Type

**Date Difference Formula**
[image: DateDiff Formula]

**Assign Values in Variables**
[image: Assign Values in Variables]

Comment: Thanks. This worked.

Comment: Please mark this as answer so that question can be closed.