# How to find days difference between two dates in a formula Field in visual Flow builder in salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, formula-field

I'm pretty new to salesforce, and the only closely related information I could find related to the subject matter was provided in this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265866/months-between-dates-in-flow).
I'm basically working in a flow builder and I want to find the days between two dates.
I'm looking something similar to this. `DAY({!EndDate}) - DAY({!StartDate}) *  MONTH( {!EndDate}) + 12 - MONTH( {!StartDate}) + 12 * (YEAR(EndDate) - YEAR(StartDate) -1)`  which should roughly give the answer equal to 2, if the start date is 18, march 2020, and the end date is 20, march 2020. The above formula may not be correct.
Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Days between two dates (assuming both fields are of type Date)

```
{!EndDate} - {!StartDate}
```

The link you provided in the OP was for getting the months between dates which is a harder problem than days between dates

Comment: Thank you! that worked out!